# How to make a loop in this selenium test

Tags: python, selenium, loops

Hi guys I am still learning selenium and basics of coding so sorry for noob question :)

I have a list of links in the CSV
I want to open each link, do some action and go to another link from CSV list, but if the website doesnt have that button I want just to move to another link from the csv

For now when the page has those elements i can loop trough, but sometimes this page doesnt have this elements and wants to redirect me to external site.
I have value like this on the page:

```
<p class="uk-text-large uk-text-center uk-alert">You are leaving this site</p>
```

'

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'external', 'click', 
'logedin');" id="submit" value="redirect" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large">
```

I would like if selenium finds on the page text ***"You are leaving this site"*** or value ***"redirect"*** on the page just to move to another link from the list.

This is the first part that works when all pages have button and dont want to redirect me to the external site

One extra moment as well would be if i could add a note was the link skipped or not the CSV as new column

'

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import config
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

df = pd.read_csv("listofurls.csv")
df = pd.read_csv('listofurls.csv')
urls = df['link']

for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://www.website.com/login?redirect=%2F')
    driver.maximize_window()

    usernamebox = driver.find_element_by_id("Email_login")
    usernamebox.send_keys(config.email)

    passbox = driver.find_element_by_id("Password_login")
    passbox.send_keys(config.password)

    loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password_login"]')
    loginbutton.submit()
    time.sleep(3)
    #data = {}
    driver.get(url)

    cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__allow_ct_container"]/div/div/a')
    cookies.click()

    cv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='293608']")
    cv.click()

    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__submit"]')
    submit.click()

    #driver.close()
print('done')
```

Comment: You wish to find if an element exists on a page or not? That can easily be done via a ```try except``` block or by ```if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath): #code```

Comment: I want if I see on the page text: You are leaving this site to skip on another link

xpath of element is same on both pages ''' //*[@id="__submit"] '''

Comment: Could you please share the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

An element having id `__submit` and containing `foo` text can be found using the following XPATH:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__submit' and contains(text(), 'foo')]")
```

Have a look at [this](https://devhints.io/xpath) XPATH cheatsheet.